# Shell scripting selecting a part of a word

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

Shell scripting - I need to get only "v1.0.42" from below. There is no space between any words here

```
"ansible-project-development-environment-TEMPLATE-v1.0.42-role_test_example_run_environment"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
echo "ansible-project-development-environment-TEMPLATE-v1.0.42-role_test_example_run_environment" | cut -d '-' -f6
```

Comment: Avoid "try this:" answers. It implies that you are unsure if your solution is correct and that the other person should just "try this" and see if it works. Instead, add an explanation of why what you did works. You step into the role of teacher when answering on SO, so be a good one... Just a bit of helpful advise, not a ding.

Comment: I will improve my answer in future. Thank for your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*(v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/  Input_file
```

OR with BRE `sed` as per David sir's comments:

```
sed 's/^.*-\(v[^-][^-]*\).*$/\1/' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** With `perl` one liner.

```
perl -ne 'print "$&\n" if /v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/'  Input_file
```

Comment: Or BRE `sed  's/^.*-\(v[^-][^-]*\).*$/\1/'`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bash and the above string in var `$var`:

```
$ [[ $var =~ v([0-9]+\.?)+ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
v1.0.42
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the string in a shell variable, you could use [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) to remove the parts you don't want:

```
v="ansible-project-development-environment-TEMPLATE-v1.0.42-role_test_example_run_environment"
v=${v#*-TEMPLATE-}   #  v1.0.42-role_test_example_run_environment
v=${v%%-*}           #  v1.0.42
```

This is standard POSIX shell, not requiring any non-standard extensions.

Relevant quote:

> #### `${parameter#[word]}`
>
> **Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern.** The *word* shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in
>   *parameter*, with the smallest portion of the prefix matched by the
>   *pattern* deleted. If present, word shall not begin with an unquoted
>   '`#`'.
>
> #### `${parameter%%[word]}`
>
> **Remove Largest Suffix Pattern.** The *word* shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in
>   *parameter*, with the largest portion of the suffix matched by the
>   *pattern* deleted.